# Writing Upcasting and Downcasting expressions in c#

Tags: c#, downcast, upcasting

I have been recently studying upcasting and downcasting in c#. I understand that upcasting refers to conversion from a derived class to a base class. However, when i see a practical example of upcasting (like below), i get confused.

```
public class Shape 
{
...
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
...
}

Circle circle = new Circle();
Shape shape = new Shape();
// Converting an object into its base class reference
shape = circle
```

If we are converting circle into its base class reference, shouldn't it be like

```
circle = shape
```

Sorry if it sounds too amateur. This is because I have always seen expressions in the following format:

```
int x = 3; // means assign 3 to variable x.
```

So I am just confused why circle is on the right hand side and not on the left hand side. Please advise. Consider me a beginner.

Comment: Related/similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991242/upcasting-and-downcasting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818251/understanding-up-casting-and-down-casting-c-sharp. All of those references explained how casting works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Aside: This is called *upcasting* because, traditionally, class diagrams are drawn such that the base classes are shown physically above the derived classes.)

Now when you do:

```
shape = circle; // shape->(instance of Circle)
```

you are assigning a `Circle` reference to a `Shape` reference, so that after the assignment the reference `shape` will be referencing a `Circle`.

This is fine, because everything you can do with a `Shape` you can also do with a `Circle`.

If, however, you do:

```
circle = shape; // circle->(instance of Shape)
```

you are assigning a `Shape` reference to a `Circle` reference. You can't do this because (if this were possible) you would then be able to access `Circle` features that are not present in a `Shape`.

For example, imagine that `Circle.Radius` exists but `Shape.Radius` does not.

If you were allowed to point the `circle` reference at a `Shape` what would happen if you tried to access `circle.Radius`? The answer would be: undefined behaviour would happen, because `Shape.Radius` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

No

The problem is: a `Shape` is not a `Circle`, but a `Circle` is a `Shape`.

This means that a `Circle` always can be placed into a spot where a `Shape` is required, but when you need a `Circle` you could not throw into its place any `Shape` as it may also be a `Triangle`.

This is why you need to explicitly cast it up (either using `(Type)variable` or `variable as Type`).

Essentially, lets assume the following:

```
class Shape {}
class Circle : Shape {}
class Triangle : Shape {}
```

Now, we also have a `Triangle` allowing us to actually get this layed out better:

```
Circle c = new Circle();
Triangle t = c; // Impossible due to Circle not being a Triangle
Shape s = c; // Possible because a Circle is a Shape
Triangle t2 = s; // Impossible because Shape may be a Triangle or any other derived class
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically doing in your example can also be written as the following:

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
Shape shape = (Shape)circle; //Casting the object to the base type
```

So you are casting your object of type `Circle` to an object of type `Shape`.
In your code this is "automatically" done because you are assining the value to a new variable of type `Shape`.

This explains the casting/base classes a little bit more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Answer (score 1):

if you know about set, you can easily understand why 'shape = circle' is able, 'circle = shape' is not able.

think about this.

A is a character of Alphabet.

so we can say

```
public class A : Alphabet
{
}
```

as we know.

also Alphabet is

```
public class Alphabet
{
}
```

if we draw a diagram, it can be like this

```
┌───────── Alphabet ───────┐
│ A B C D E ... a b c ... z│
└──────────────────────────┘
```

We can say z is Alphabet, but we cannot say Alplabet is z because Alphabet contains more than z.

so, Let's see Circle and Shape.

Circle contains information of Shape and it has been added more variables. (possibly it does not, but can be changed. )

So we can say Circle is a set of Shape.

We can modify Circle which is based on Shape. Also we can Initialize Circle.

but if you do 'Shape = Circle', some of things which is in Circle cannot be initialized.

and it returns error.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain:

The *variable* `shape` contains a *reference* to an object of type `Shape`.

When you write `Shape shape = new Shape();` The variable `shape` will contain a reference to a new `Shape` object.

When you reassign `shape` by writing `shape = circle` it contains a reference to another object. The object `circle` is of type `circle`, but since circle inherits `shape` it is OK to do this assignment; there is an implicit cast done of the `circle` to type `Shape`.

Another and perhaps clearer way to do this cast would be to make an explicit cast:

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
Shape circleAsShape = (Shape)circle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Upcasting means changing type of an object to a less derived base class (`Circle` object to `Sape`).

Downcasting works in the other direction, eg. casting from `Shape` to `Circle`.

Variable of more derived type can be easily assigned to variable of less derived type, because upcasting is done implicitly here, because `Circle` is also a `Shape`. That's why value of more derived type can be assigned to a vairable of less derived type.

It doesn't work the other way, since `Shape` is general and we don't know if it's a `Circle`. Thus, when you try downcasting, you need to specify it explicitly:

```
// this won't work
Shape shape = new Shape();
Circle c = (Circle)shape;
// this will
Shape shape = new Circle();
// we know we have Circle object so we can downcast
Circle c = (Circle)shape;
```